# Testing Rails Deep Nested Attributes with RSPEC and FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I need some help getting my factory_girl settings correct on this has one through many with nested attributes. Here's the three models for reference.

location.rb

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_locations
  has_many :people, through: :person_locations
end
```

person_location.rb

```
class PersonLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_locations
  has_many :locations, through: :person_locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person_locations, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

Notice that locations is nested under the person record, but it needs to go through two models to be nested. I can get the tests working like this:

```
it "creates the objects and can be called via rails syntax" do 
   Location.all.count.should == 0
   @person = FactoryGirl.create(:person)
   @location = FactoryGirl.create(:location)
   @person_location = FactoryGirl.create(:person_location, person: @person, location: @location)
   @person.locations.count.should == 1
   @location.people.count.should == 1
   Location.all.count.should == 1
end
```

I should be able to create all three of these records within one line but haven't figured out how to yet. Here's the structure I would like to have work correctly :

```
factory :person do 
  ...
  trait :location_1 do 
    person_locations_attributes { location_attributes { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:location, :location_1) } }
  end
end
```

I have other models which are able to create via a similar syntax, but it has only one nested attribute versus this deeper nesting.

As entered above, I get the following error:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:person, :location_1)

   undefined method `location_attributes' for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x007fd65102a380>
```

Furthermore, I want to be able to test properly my controller setup for creating a new user with nested location. It will be tough to do this if I can't get the call down to one line.

Thanks for your help!! Hopefully I provided enough above to help others as well when they are creating a has many through relationship with nested attributes.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of days later I figured it out after reading [blog 1](http://joekratzat.com/blog/2013/carrierwave-rspec-and-factorygirl/) and [blog 2](http://gaslight.co/blog/6-ways-to-remove-pain-from-feature-testing-in-ruby-on-rails?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email). In the process of refactoring all of my FactoryGirl code now.

FactoryGirl should look as follows:

```
factory :person do 
...
  trait :location_1 do 
    after(:create) do |person, evaluator|
      create(:person_location, :location_1, person: person)
    end
  end
end
```

The person_location factory should be pretty straight forward then following the above code. You can either do the location_attributes which is in the original question or create a similar block to this answer to handle it there.

Comment: Another good resource is http://robots.thoughtbot.com/remove-duplication-with-factorygirls-traits